# Pygame.set_colorkey() issues

Tags: colors, pygame, pixel, surface

I made this pixel art dude but I just want him not the background. The guys a bmp file since png files arent working in pygame for me, The background color I used was CCCCCC which is 80,80,80 RGB color value, So I did, GameDisplay.set_colorkey(transcolor) after I blited the image. Transcolor was = (80,80,80) and so I thought this would work but it doesnt. Anyone know what I can do? The full code is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
import time #Modules
import random
pygame.init()
black = (0,0,0) #Colors
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (72,94,181)
silver = (173,178,189)
brown = (102,51,0)
gray = (64,64,64)
transcolor = (0,0,0)
GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1400,750)) #Display
pygame.display.set_caption("Internet Adventure")
#Images
TitleScreen = pygame.image.load('InternetAdventureTitleScreen2.bmp')
DefaultMan = pygame.image.load('Buisnessman.bmp')
def mts(text, textcolor, x, y, fs):
    font = pygame.font.Font(None,fs)
    text = font.render(text, True, textcolor)
    GameDisplay.blit(text, [x,y])
def button(x,y,w,h,ic,ac):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(GameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1:
            print("Kaboom")  
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(GameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))
def button2(x,y,w,h,ic,ac):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
            pygame.draw.rect(GameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

            if click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()  
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(GameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))
def aboutscreen():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pygame.display.update()
def StartUpScreen():
    global transcolor

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        GameDisplay.blit(DefaultMan, (0,0))
        GameDisplay.set_colorkey(transcolor)
        button(285, 230, 290, 120, brown, brown)
        mts("Play", black, 350, 260, 90)
        button2(750, 230, 320, 120, brown, brown)
        mts("Quit", black, 840, 260, 90)
        pygame.display.update()
StartUpScreen()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `.set_colorkey(transcolor)` on the `Surface` you want to be partially transparent, *not* the screen surface (`GameDisplay`).

Call it on `DefaultMan` after loading the image:

```
DefaultMan = pygame.image.load('Buisnessman.bmp')
DefaultMan.set_colorkey(transcolor)
...
```